# Export/Import customized Perspective programmatically in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, export, epf

I'm using a software called Teamcenter from Siemens which is a branch of Eclipse.
We want to achieve that we create our own customized Perspective (reordering of Views of an OOTB Perspective with a new name) and publish it for a global standard of our clients.

The commands to do it manually (export the *.epf file of the perspective and import it on the other client) are disabled in Teamcenter but if I can do it programmatically I can see a way to achieve our requirement.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: In Eclipse 4 perspectives are just part of the application model in the `e4xmi` file. [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ModelPersistence/article.html#saving-and-restoring-parts-of-the-application-model) shows how to save parts of the model separately.

Comment: Thanks for this tutorial but Teamcenter in Version 10.1, which we are using, is based on Eclipse 3.8.

So i cannot use this methods of the tutorial...   :-(